# createUrl is not creating URL in the path format

Tags: url, yii, yii-url-manager

I am trying to create a URL in the path format in yii but it always creates it in the get format. I do not understand whats going wrong.

this is the **main.php**

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                            'showScriptName'=>FALSE,
                'rules'=>array(
'airlineSearch/roundTripSearch/<origin:\w+>'=>'airlineSearch/roundTripSearch/<origin>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                ),
            ),
```

and this is the **controller**

```
class AirlineSearchController extends Controller
{
public function actionRoundTripSearch($origin)
       {
           echo $origin;   
       }

       public function actionLets()
       {
          echo $this->createUrl('roundTripSearch',array('origin'=>'delhi'));
       }
}
```

but it always results in `/services/airlineSearch/roundTripSearch?origin=delhi` 
**Question** :- How can i get it in the path format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
'rules'=>array(
'airlineSearch/roundTripSearch/<origin:\w+>'=>'airlineSearch/roundTripSearch',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                ),
```

I just removed the <origin> from

`'airlineSearch/roundTripSearch/<origin:\w+>'=>'airlineSearch/roundTripSearch/<origin>`',

Comment: Nice answer. +1 for both Q & A :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend removing the default Yii URL rules and add your own, specific ones. Also try using [useStrictParsing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#useStrictParsing-detail). Both of these help to control your URLs more closely and will generate 404s as appropriate.

This would be my approach:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'useStrictParsing'=>true,
    'rules'=>array(

        'services/airline-search/<trip:round-trip|one-way>/<origin:\w+>' => 'airlineSearch/roundTripSearch',
    ),
),
```

And then in your controller:

```
<?php

class AirlineSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function actionRoundTripSearch($origin)
    {
        print_r($_GET); // Array ( [trip] => round-trip [origin] => delhi )

        // Use the full route as first param 'airlineSearch/roundTripSearch'
        // This may have been the cause of your issue
        echo $this->createUrl('airlineSearch/roundTripSearch',array('trip' => 'round-trip', 'origin'=>'delhi'));
        // echoes  /services/airline-search/round-trip/delhi
    }

    public function actionLets()
    {

    }


?>
```